# Force NSBrowser to reload

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm new to Cocoa so apologies if this doesn't make sense.

I'm using an `NSBrowser` to get a Finder-style column view of some data from a web service.
The `NSURLConnection` result is returned asynchronously.

My issue is that the browser correctly calls its delegate to populate columns when the app starts, but I can't make it reload once I've got the data.

I've tried `reloadDataForRowIndexes`, `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged`, `addColumn`, `reloadColumn` and `loadColumnZero`, but none of them trigger  the browser to call `numberOfRowsInColumn` on the delegate as I would expect (and see on startup).

I know the browser delegate is ok because I can see it being called at startup.

Is there another way to ask the browser to refresh, or do I need to try another approach?

Plan B would be to fire the urlConnection off on another thread, and block the browser. I'm not keen on blocking the UI thread as I fear this will cause a beachball.

Plan C maybe would be to delay the browser loading from the nib file until the data was ready, but I'd have a similar issue next node unless I load all nodes a column early in anticipation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[browser reloadColumn:0]` is the right way to go. This just works, no workaround needed. Your error is elsewhere if this does not work for you.

Comment: Well this reduced my search radius considerably! Turns out that my local browser reference is not set by Interface Builder as I expected, but it is passed in to the delegate method ok. Cheers.

Comment: This was caused by renaming an IBOutlet in a header file. I had linked the NSBrowser to the new name, but not deleted the old link. Also, this was shown in the build warnings, but only on a clean rebuild.

Answer (score 6):

`[browser reloadColumn:0]` did not work for me but `[browser loadColumnZero]`.